# Allow drawing in an existing activity/fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-canvas, ondraw

I have an activity that controls 3 fragments and I want to allow drawing on each of the fragment screens (tab bar at the top to change fragment views). Most of the tutorials I see on drawing include creating some drawing view class in which an activity uses to set it's content view. However, my activity already has it's own content view from an xml file.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

How would I go about adding drawing functionality to my existing system? Thanks!